# Looking For Rolling Total Aggregated By Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I've looked and I've found running totals, but nothing that groups the dates together by years and months.  The results I'm getting from the query below show me the rolling balance by date, and compounded by the count of transactions for each day.

```
select 
    acct,
    year(trans_date) 'Year',
    month(trans_date) 'Month',
    sum(dom_amount) over (partition by acct order by year(trans_date), month(trans_date)) as TotalBalance
from ledger_mst
where acct = 1100
group by 
    dom_amount, 
    acct,
    year(trans_date),
    month(trans_date),
    trans_date
order by trans_date
```

As of right now, I should have 39 rows (Sep 2015 - Nov 2018) with each year and month and rolling balance at the end of the month.  I currently have 16,477 rows in my results. It appears that my group by is broken, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

My SQL skills are mediocre at best.  Go easy on me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should include the neither the `dom_amount` nor the `trans_date` in your `group by` clause, as this will cause every different value of these fields to generate a new result line...

Accordingly you need to change your `order by` clause.

Just remove that from your query and it should work fine. Also remove the `over` clause.

```
select 
    acct,
    year(trans_date) 'Year',
    month(trans_date) 'Month',
    sum(dom_amount) TotalBalance
from ledger_mst
where acct = 1100
group by 
    acct,
    year(trans_date),
    month(trans_date)
order by
    year(trans_date),
    month(trans_date)
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response!  Without dom_amount in the group by I get this error:

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Column 'ledger_mst.dom_amount' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Hello @ChrisL are you sure that you are running the exact same query that I put in my answer ?  The only  `dom_amount` that I have in my `select` clause is at line 5 (not 6), and it is part of an aggregate function (`sum`).

Comment: I just copied your exact query and I'm still receiving the same error just now, except on Line 5.  Line 1 I have the use clause to select the database I want to use was ran yesterday.  Does the over clause break the aggregate function? If I comment out the over clause the results are 39 rows, as expected.

Comment: @ChrisL well that would have been my next try... I think you don’t need the `over` clause anyway to fit your need. Just edited my answer accordingly. Thanks !

Comment: The over clause is necessary to give me a running total.  If there's a way to sum current row to previous row, that may work from the aggregated sum of dom_amount, I just don't need the detail.